# <input type="date" max="{{max}}"> does not set max date angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, datepicker

I have following HTML code

```
<input class="col-5" type="date"
                   max="{{ vm.maxDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd' }}"
                   min="{{ vm.minDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd' }}"
                   ng-model="vm.endBy">
```

and following is the angular js code in controller

```
vm.minDate = new Date(moment.utc().format(dateFormat));
vm.maxDate = new Date(moment.utc().format(dateFormat));
vm.endBy = new Date(moment.utc().format(dateFormat));

vm.maxDate.setDate(vm.minDate.getDate()+ 185);
vm.endBy.setDate(vm.minDate.getDate() + 185);
```

Now my calendar is showing till the maxDate with date selected as maxdate But when I submit the form it shows as undefined. Also I tried to print the endBy in the HTML but it is not showing the maxDate. However, for all other dates earlier than maxDate it is working fine.

I don't know what's wrong with this. Did anyone know why it is behaving like this ? Is max validation does not check for equal and why endBy date set in input box while i submit it it says undefined?

Comment: `But when I submit the form it shows as undefined. `  Did you forgot to set `name` attribute ?

Comment: The `name` attribute is used to reference elements in a JavaScript, or to reference form data after a form is submitted. Only form elements with a `name` attribute will have their values passed when submitting a form.

Comment: It is working for dates less than maxDate. ng-model binds it automatically.

Comment: Why are you not using property binding? instead of putting inside mustash syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an invalid date when you do

```
new Date(moment.utc().format( 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
```

Try

```
vm.minDate = new Date();
vm.maxDate = new Date();
vm.endBy = new Date();
```

Comment: dateFormat is 'yyyy-MM-dd' . but this issue exists even if i am using new Date(); Also with new Date(moment.utc().format(dateFormat)); dates seems valid.